# e.preventDefault & e.stopImmediatePropagation not working

Tags: javascript, joomla, preventdefault

I got a problem where `preventDefault()` are not working properly.
This ajax request is working and I get the php page to show in the selected `div`, but the `preventDefault` is not working. For the map area that have a link I got redirected to the page, and for the ones that have no link, the address bar got an added "#" to the url. (in this last case, the ajax calls get correctly appended to the `div`, but still, `preventDefault` not doing its job).

After doing some digging I found out something : `stopImmediatePropagation()`
I was really hyped by this for a few seconds before seeing that it had absolutely no effect on my side too. I must be missing something but I can't find it.

*More infos: The website is on joomla 3x, on localhost and showing K2 itemview categories on this ajax request.*

Any help really really welcomed.

```
window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', (event) => {
 var xmlhttp;
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
        xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    } else {
        xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
      }
    let links = document.querySelectorAll('map area')
    console.log(links)
    for (let i = 0 ; i < links.length ; i++) {
        let link = links[i]
        link.addEventListener('click', function (e) {
            e.preventDefault
            e.stopImmediatePropagation()
            xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
                if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
                        document.getElementById('maploc-loc').innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
                    }
                }
            xmlhttp.open("GET", '../index.php?option=com_k2&view=itemlist&layout=category&task=category&id=1&id=Itemid=1',true);
            xmlhttp.send();
        })
      }  
});
```

Comment: invoke preventDefault: `e.preventDefault()`

Comment: What is `let links = document.querySelectorAll('map area')` 'map area' here?

Comment: I really just forgot () for preventDefautl and i feel ashamed.